# How to share configurations of WSO2-IS among servers?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have multiple `wso2-is` server set up as my `dev`, `staging` and `prod` environment.

And I would want to have a functionality wherein I can export all the configuration from some server ( say `dev` ) to some other server ( say `staging` ) to make both the server identical 
i.e both the server would have same database configurations, same tenants, same service providers and same identity providers and so on.

From the documentation [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS560/Configuring+a+SP+and+IdP+Using+Configuration+Files), I know that I can create service providers and identity providers using XML files, so in turn, I can share the XML files to sync SPs and IdPs between servers.

But is there a standard way to achieve that? Like, from the management console or so?

It even seems possible that syncing between `[IS-HOME]/repository` directory would ensure that the servers are identical, But are there any caveats for this approach?

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard way to sync the service provider configurations among different environment, as of now. [This](https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/3346) issue is reported to track the feature requirement and its a work in progress at the moment and you can expect it in a future release.

One possible solution you can use to achieve your target is, retrieving the service provider from the [Admin service](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS550/Using+the+Service+Provider+API) and create the same service provider in other environment.

You can use the file based service provider configurations to achieve this target. But with that approach, you will not be able to see the service providers added from the configuration files in the management console. Next limitation you will face is you can add saml based inbound authentication configurations only through the config files ( such as OAuth 2.0 / OIDC inbound authentication configurations)

To answer your last question, you can't sync the `[IS-HOME]/repository` folder to achieve this. The reason you were able to observe this behavior seems to be you are using the inbuilt H2 database and its in `[IS-HOME]/repository/database` folder. With your file sync, you have actually synced the databases.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so would it be possible to sync if both the servers point to same database and `[IS-HOME]/repository` is copied?!